# How to read and edit a FASTA file with python using regular expression?

Tags: python

I have a file containing protein sequence information of 100 odd proteins. Each sequence starts with a header that looks like this:

```
>sp|Q9UDW1|QCR9_HUMAN Cytochrome b-c1 complex subunit 9 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=UQCR10 PE=1 SV=3
```

I want to edit these header to look like this:

```
>Q9UDW1
```

I have tried the following code:

```
import re
with open ('WT.fasta', 'r+') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(contents)-1):
        target = re.compile(r'>..\|(.*)\|.*', contents[i])    
        target.sub(r'\1', contents[i])
```

I think I am not being able to call the right methods to do this. I have been trying to read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html. I am not been able to understand it and feeling overwhelmed by the details. I would really appreciate if anyone could help or point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use python? A simple `sed` would do this much faster.

Comment: Hi @RamRS, I am actually very new to bioinformatics. I still have not learnt about ```sed``` or ```awk``` commands :-)

Comment: You definitely should - these will save you a lot of time for tasks that are too small in get Python/R involved.

Comment: @RamRS, I would love learn about them. Would you have any suggestions about any course, or tutorials on these topics?

Comment: Just google around. The way to learn these would be using them on copies of files for tasks like your current question - start there and you'll find more and more places you can use them.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I usually recommend Biopython for any sort of fasta parsing, but the code below should work as well.

```py
with open ('WT.fasta', 'r+') as in_f, open("WT_out.fasta", 'w') as out_f:
    for line in in_f:
        if line[0] == ">":
            out_f.write(">" + line.split('|')[1] + "\n")
        else:
            out_f.write(line)
```

Comment: Hi, The code executes, does not show any error messages. But the file looks the same as before!

Comment: @Noob which file are you looking at? The code creates a new file WT_out.fasta

Comment: Oh sorry! My bad :/... I am an absolute idiot!

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with `awk` by processing the header:

```
$ awk -v FS="|" '{ if ($0 ~ /^>/) { printf(">%s\n", $2) } else print $0 }' in.fa > out.fa
```

For example:

```
% echo -e ">sp|Q9UDW1|QCR9_HUMAN Cytochrome b-c1 complex subunit 9 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=UQCR10 PE=1 SV=3\nACCGT" | awk -v FS="|" '{ if ($0 ~ /^>/) { printf(">%s\n", $2) } else print $0 }' 
>Q9UDW1
ACCGT
```

Comment: Hi @AlexReynolds, Thanks a lot! I will try it.